# MySQL Access denied for user Error when application hosted on different server from DB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, apache, perl

I have 2 different server, one server (`server1`) hosts the perl application and the other server (`server2`) hosts the MYSQL DB (DBNAME= `hpdb`).

The perl application on server1 is suppose to get mysql results from server2. When I try to do this I get the error message `Access denied for user 'userrego'@'server1.domain.com' (using password: YES)`.

However, when I host the perl application on `server2`, the application works as expected.

I tried to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON hpdb.* TO 'userrego'@'server1.domain.com'` but still couldn't get it to work.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'userrego'@'server1.domain.com';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for userrego@server1.domain.com                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'userrego'@'server1.domain.com'               |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hpdb`.* TO 'userrego'@'server1.domain.com' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Im basically laying in bed and going to sleep, so not able to figure out things nor type a proper answer :p, but what I wanna say is I remember some option in the mysql config denying access for every remote connection. Maybe it has something to do with that, maybe not :p

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you should please verify:

Please make sure *skip-networking* in my.cnf is disabled. If *bind-address* is set, make sure it is appropriately set, depending on the network config of server2. Do a service mysql restart if you changed anything.

If it still does not work I would verify that the password and source ip is not the issue by (if possible) creating another user to connect with - you can always remove it after testing. Issue a grant with:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hpdb`.* TO 'userregotest'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxx'

With that you will be sure of the correct password and that the source ip address is not the issue since any source address will be able to connect.

If none of this works, we might need to inspect things a bit closer.